# Recargar la pagina al hacer submit en un form que consume una API

Tags: html5, nodejs, api

tengo un formulario en una ventana modal, que hace un POST a una API en el servidor, y despues el servidor guarda la informacion en la BD. El servidor esta hecho con Node Js y express.
El problema es que al hacer el submit, se abre la direcion IP de la API, y lo que yo necesito es que se vuelva a recargar la pagina principal de mi aplicacion. 
Ademas, como capturo la respuesta desde el servidor si la operacion fue exitosa o hubo un error... aqui el codigo del frontend:

```
<form action = {apiUrl} method = "POST">
    <div className = "booking-checkOut">
      <label >Check Out: </label>
      <input type = "date" min = {minDate} name = "checkOut" required />
    </div>
    <div className = "booking-pasajero">
      <input name = "idPasajero" placeholder = "Nro identificacion" />
      <input name = "pasajero" placeholder = "pasajero" required/>
      <input type="email" placeholder ="email" />
      <input name = "nacionalidad" placeholder = "nacionalidad" />
    </div>
    <div className = "booking-booking">
      <p>Datos de la Reserva</p>
      <input type = "number" name = "cantPas" placeholder = "Cantidad de Pasajeros" min = "1" required/>
      <input type = "number" name = "tarifa" placeholder = "tarifa" step = "0.01" min = "10" required/>
      <textarea name = "observ" placeholder = "Observaciones"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "room" value = {props.data.roomNumb} />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "checkIn" value = {props.data.checkIn} />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "habitacionId" value = {props.data.roomID} />
    <button type = "submit" className = "modal-btn primary">Confirmar</button>
  </form>
  <button
   className = "Modal-close"
   onClick={props.clickCerrar}
   ></button>
```

y en el servidor tengo esta ruta:

```
app.post(`${API_BASE}/new-booking`, (req, res) => {
  data(req.body)
      .then (pgdata => {
        res.send("ok")
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

que recibe los datos del form y con la funcion data lo guarda en la base de datos.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que estas realizando la petición a directamente desde el formulario, esto se puede realizar siempre que en el servidor haga una re-dirección. En este caso lo más conveniente es realizar la petición con JS, agregando el siguiente código a tu página.

## JS

```js
async function submitHandler() {
  try {
    // Obtener los valores del formulario
    const checkOutEl = document.getElementsByName('checkOut')[0];
    const checkOut = checkOutEl.value;

    const idPasajeroEl = document.getElementsByName('idPasajero')[0];
    const idPasajero = idPasajeroEl.value;

    const pasajeroEl = document.getElementsByName('pasajero')[0];
    const pasajero = pasajeroEl.value;

    const emailEl = document.getElementsByName('email')[0];
    const email = emailEl.value;

    const nacionalidadEl = document.getElementsByName('nacionalidad')[0];
    const nacionalidad = nacionalidadEl.value;

    const cantPasEl = document.getElementsByName('cantPas')[0];
    const cantPas = cantPasEl.value;

    const tarifaEl = document.getElementsByName('tarifa')[0];
    const tarifa = tarifaEl.value;

    const observEl = document.getElementsByName('observ')[0];
    const observ = observEl.value;

    const roomEl = document.getElementsByName('room')[0];
    const room = roomEl.value;

    const checkInEl = document.getElementsByName('checkIn')[0];
    const checkIn = checkInEl.value;

    const habitacionIdEl = document.getElementsByName('habitacionId')[0];
    const habitacionId = habitacionIdEl.value;

  
    const formData = { checkOut, idPasajero, pasajero, email, nacionalidad, cantPas, tarifa, observ, room, checkIn, habitacionId };
  
    if (checkOut && idPasajero && pasajero && email && nacionalidad && cantPas && tarifa && observ && room && checkIn && habitacionId) {
      
      const url = '/api/post';
  
      const method = 'POST';
  
      const config = {
        method,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      };
      // petición
      const response = await fetch(url, config);
      if (response) {
        // respuesta del servidor
        if (response.ok) {
          // obtener los datos de la respuesta
          const data = await response.json(); // puede ser .text(), .blob(), .arrayBuffer() o formData().
          // hacer algo con los datos ...

          // recargar página
          window.location.reload();

          // reiniciar valores del formulario, descomentar si no desea regarcar la página
          // checkOutEl.value = null;
          // idPasajeroEl.value = null;
          // pasajeroEl.value = null;
          // emailEl.value = null;
          // nacionalidadEl.value = null;
          // cantPasEl.value = null;
          // tarifaEl.value = null;
          // observEl.value = null;
          // roomEl.value = null;
          // checkInEl.value = null;
          // habitacionIdEl.value = null;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('parametros no validos');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('submitHandler', error);
  }
}
```

## HTML

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitHandler()">
    <div className="booking-checkOut">
      <label>Check Out: </label>
      <input name="checkOut" type="date" required />
    </div>
    <div className="booking-pasajero">
      <input name="idPasajero" placeholder="Nro identificacion" />
      <input name="pasajero" placeholder="pasajero" required />
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" />
      <input name="nacionalidad" placeholder="nacionalidad" />
    </div>
    <div className="booking-booking">
      <p>Datos de la Reserva</p>
      <input type="number" name="cantPas" placeholder="Cantidad de Pasajeros" min="1" required />
      <input type="number" name="tarifa" placeholder="tarifa" step="0.01" min="10" required />
      <textarea name="observ" placeholder="Observaciones"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value={props.data.roomNumb} />
    <input type="hidden" name="checkIn" value={props.data.checkIn} />
    <input type="hidden" name="habitacionId" value={props.data.roomID} />
    <button type="submit" className="modal-btn primary">Confirmar</button>
  </form>
  <button className="Modal-close" onClick={props.clickCerrar}></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

al botón quizás te falta agregar e.preventDefault();
o quizás con la respuesta del servidor necesitas hacer una validación en el cliente para que si te da la respuesta que esperas pueda recargar la página

Comment: serías tan amable de ser mas preciso con tu respuesta, por que parece mas una opinión al indicarle que **quizás** podrían ser 2 soluciones